# Mass Editing "stock_route_product"

Tags: odoo

i have loaded the products (1500 more or less) in odoo but i just find out that i need to modify the route for nearly 1000 products. In a couple of steps, using Qlikview, excel a sublime i have created the query to change those products.

Look like this:

```
 insert into stock_route_product (route_id, product_id) values
 ('1','1546'),
 ('1','1547'),...,...,...;
```

But postgreSql give me back this error:

```
Query execution failed

Reason:
Error SQL [23503]: ERRORE: the INSERT or UPDATE on the table 
"stock_route_product" viola il vincolo di chiave esterna (translated: 
violates the foreign key constraint)
"stock_route_product_product_id_fkey"
```

For the record is odoo 12 comunity in a windows Environment

thanks to all the repliers --> "A buon rendere"

I tried to write directly into the database and to insert just less row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is foreign key so first you need to add necessary products to product table to satisfy foreign key requirements (the same problem can be for route). Something like:

```
insert into product (product_id) values
```

Comment: i found the problem seems that i was using the product_id instead the joint was with product_template id. so postgres was not founding the key, i changed the query naw it's working.

thanks for the collaboration!

Thenks